# Database column requires int, but doesn't throw exception when string is inputted

Tags: java, xml, database

I have a rest service which has a database. When I add an entity to my database in an EJB using a entityfacade, one entity variable price requires an real. If I input the price as a string in xml format from a client, no exception is thrown and the database registers 0 instead. If I make the variable too large the proper exception is thrown.

Any ideas of why this is happening? Or is there a way if setting my database table to accept integer only?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS", catalog = "", schema = "DAVID")
@XmlRootElement

public class Books implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
//@NotNull
@Column(name = "BOOKID")
private Integer bookid;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ISBN")
private long isbn;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 40)
@Column(name = "PUBLISHER")
private String publisher;
@Column(name = "QUANTITY")
private int quantity;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "PRICE")
private float price;

CREATE TABLE BOOKS (BOOKID INTEGER DEFAULT AUTOINCREMENT: start 1 increment 1  NOT NULL           GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, ISBN BIGINT NOT NULL, TITLE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, COPYRIGHT VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, PUBLISHER VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, QUANTITY INTEGER, PRICE REAL NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (BOOKID));
```

Comment: What database is that?

Comment: If the database does not catch it, you could use XML Schema, too.

Comment: In a javaDB database, it is difficult to figure out. The entity class in my program should only accept integers. Updated code with entity code.

Comment: How do you map XML to bean?

Comment: i left out the top part.

Comment: I use a bookfacade class to use the books entity class.